# MySQL Sort by Date Where Date >= Today first in ascending, then Date < Today in descending in 1 Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I've tried to use

```
SELECT *
FROM `activity`
WHERE 1
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN `activity_date` >= '2019-06-14' THEN `activity_date` END ASC,
    CASE WHEN `activity_date` < '2019-06-14' THEN `activity_date` END DESC,
    `activity_date` ASC
```

but it gave me the order before `2019-06-14` in descending order first, equal or later than `2019-06-14` in ascending order after it. Like

```
+----+------------+
| ID | Date       |
+----+------------+
| 5  | 2019-06-12 |
| 3  | 2019-06-11 |
| 2  | 2019-06-10 |
| 4  | 2019-06-15 |
| 1  | 2019-06-16 |
+----+------------+
```

Currently I split it into 2 queries to make sure it can return the correct order using WHERE clause instead.

However, I can't use `LIMIT start_limit, items_per_page` when I need to list the results in many pages because they have their own numbers of rows.

If I use `UNION` to combine the results, the order will be incorrect again. Therefore, if I can use 1 single query and it can return the correct order, it will be great!

Comment: Can you include sample output as you want to see it?

Comment: Sample output added.

Comment: I attempted an answer below if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there isn't actually anything wrong with your technique it's purely that your first case when doesn't output anything when the date is less than the 14th so it outputs NULL, and null ranks lower than a value so they all sort towards the start when the date is less than the 14th:

[image]

*thanks to Nick for the dbfiddle that permitted that shot*

To sort out these rows tied on null MySQL will then look at the second clause in the orderby and you end up with all your pre 14th dates before the post 14th ones

The simplest way to sort this out would be to put a high date in as an ELSE for the first case when:

```
SELECT *
FROM `activity`
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN `activity_date` >= '2019-06-14' THEN `activity_date` ELSE '2999-01-01' END ASC,
    CASE WHEN `activity_date` < '2019-06-14' THEN `activity_date` END DESC
```

This will make all those nulls in the screenshot become 2099-01-01 which is chronologically after the real dates, so the first sort would place them at the end of the results not the start. All your post 14th dates come first, all your pre dates would be tied as 2999-01-01, then MySQL will use the second clause to sort out the ties

So simply put it's because nulls came first and the first case when converted all the pre dates to null, putting them at the top of the results

---

However, it's not particularly self explanatory why you might have a magic date of 2999 in your query and in cases like this I've always preferred to have a more explicit ordering. If you make a coarse sort effort first using something that sort before each other, like integers:

```
SELECT *
FROM `activity`
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN `activity_date` >= '2019-06-14' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN `activity_date` >= '2019-06-14' THEN `activity_date` END ASC,
    CASE WHEN `activity_date` < '2019-06-14' THEN `activity_date` END DESC
```

Then it's more obvious that you intend the post 14th to come first without the next developer needing to remember and realise that nulls come first

Output will be like:

```
2019-06-14 --sorted by 0, then date
2019-06-15 --sorted by 0, then date
2019-06-16 --sorted by 0, then date
2019-06-13 --sorted by 1, then date
2019-06-12 --sorted by 1, then date
2019-06-11 --sorted by 1, then date
```

As a general technique, you can add any number of whens to your case, with different integers, to sort more:

```
SELECT *
FROM `activity`
ORDER BY
    CASE 
      WHEN activityrating = 'gold' THEN -1 
      WHEN `activity_date` >= '2019-06-14' THEN 0 
      ELSE 1 
    END,
...
```

Puts all the gold activities first, sorted by date, then all the post 14th ones etc

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much more concise way of writing the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT ID, Date
FROM activity
ORDER BY
    Date < '2019-06-14',
    IF(Date >= '2019-06-14', 1, -1) * DATEDIFF(Date, '2019-06-14');
```

The first sorting level places records on or after `2019-06-14` first, followed by earlier records second.  Then, within each of those two groups, we sort ascending for the later records, and descending for the earlier records.

[image]

### Demo

A more general solution which would work on any database (save `DATEDIFF`, which is MySQL-specific):

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Date < '2019-06-14' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    (CASE WHEN Date >= '2019-06-14' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) *
     DATEDIFF(Date, '2019-06-14');
```

Comment: It's good, but future visitors take note it's not totally portable to other vendors that don't allow booleans to be treated like standalone values. SQLServer and Oracle wouldn't accept this, though Postgres would

Comment: @CaiusJard The boolean expressions can easily enough be converted to `CASE` expressions, and it would still leave a two-tier only sorting solution, on any database.

Comment: True, but the answer requires more work to adapt it for other vendors and uses proprietary functions - I was just pointing this out, it wasn't intended as a criticism of what is a smart technique. It may also be worth noting that it's potentially slightly harder to understand/less self documenting, and benefited from your supporting explanation

Comment: I disagree, and the accepted answer, which has three sorting levels, is actually a bit difficult to understand.

Comment: The accepted answer has a two level sort, is closer to standard sql, and can be understood by reading it. It isn't relying on a developer knowing or remembering whether true sorts ahead of false/true maps to 0, false maps to 1 (or is it the other way round? Or does false map to -1?) and it requires only a simple date (internally probably numeric) gt/lt comparison rather than a potentially more costly datediff. I welcome your edit though

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM activity
ORDER BY activity_date >= '2019-06-14' DESC,
         CASE WHEN activity_date >= '2019-06-14' THEN activity_date END ASC,
         CASE WHEN activity_date <  '2019-06-14' THEN activity_date END DESC
```

It uses a flag (`activity_date >= '2019-06-14'`) to ensure that activity dates after `2019-06-14` sort first, and the two case expressions then ensure that those dates sort ascending, and dates before `2019-06-14` sort descending.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eAkr4N54VcFUob9SUe5jX8/0)